# How to use "cargo yank"?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-crates

I've published my crate and then realized that I've forgotten to include some small detail in my `README.md`. I've included that detail into  `README.md` and did `git commit` and `push`. How to update my crate without having to change its version?

From [the `crates.io` documentation](http://doc.crates.io/crates-io.html#cargo-yank):

> `cargo yank`
>
> Occasions may arise where you publish a version of a crate that
>   actually ends up being broken for one reason or another (syntax error,
>   forgot to include a file, etc.). For situations such as this, Cargo
>   supports a `yank` of a version of a crate.
>
> ```
> $ cargo yank --vers 1.0.1 
>
> $ cargo yank --vers 1.0.1 --undo
> ```

I don't understand how to use it. Why 2 commands: one with another without `--undo`? Should I run them both? Or only one? Which?

Should I run `crate package && crate publish` after that? Or only `cargo yank ...`? Will that automatically update my crate?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You *can't* update your crate without publishing a new version.  The crate repository is explicitly designed such that crates are immutable: once published, they never change, *period.*

Yanking is for when there is some serious problem with a published crate, such as a serious security vulnerability, or potential to damage user's data, or yes, because it just straight-up doesn't work.  It's a signal that *no one* should be using that version of the crate for any reason.  An incomplete `README.md` does not really meet that standard.

Just publish a new version, or hold off until you would be publishing a new version for some other reason.

---

As for why there are two commands: because one yanks a version, and the other un-yanks it.  Un-yanking is not the same as publishing, it's just restoring the crate that was yanked as though it had never been yanked in the first place.

Comment: `It's a signal that ` -- what signal?

Comment: @Jodimoro Yanking.

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: @Jodimoro: That a version of a crate has been yanked is an indication to users that the version in question should not be used, because something is wrong with it.

Comment: What indicator? Does crates install a special red-light led indicator to each user's computer and flash it when a crate is yanked?

Comment: @Jodimoro: Yanked crates show up as yanked in a crate's version history on crates.io.